# Transmission download doesn't work when on other user

Tags: permissions, users, transmission, multiple-users

Transmission doesn't work when logged in as a normal user. Same magnet link, from the same website downloads when I use the computer as administrator, and doesn't work when I use it from a different user account. All trackers say 'connection failed'. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

See the [Ubuntu wiki Transmission HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TransmissionHowTo)

> #### Configure Users and Permissions
>
> It is recommended that Transmission runs under its own username for
> security reasons. This creates a few issues with file and folder
> access by Transmission as well as your account.

To fix it, add your user to the group debian-transmission by running this
command while logged in as the user you want to give access to, or
replace `$USER` with their username

```
sudo usermod -a -G debian-transmission $USER
```

For the change to take effect, you must log out and back in.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out myself and I want to post the answer. I made it work by switching the second user account from being 'Standard' to 'Administrator'

Comment: This is (at best) a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: I think not an answer at all since the question says "it works when I use it as administrator but not as another user" so how to use it as unprivileged user?